# Using super to make a pipeline?

Tags: python, super, boilerplate

I was thinking about how to use `super` to make a pipeline in python. I have a series of transformations I must do to a stream, and I thought that a good way to do it was something in the lines of:

```
class MyBase(object):
    def transformData(self, x):
        return x

class FirstStage(MyBase):

    def transformData(self, x):
        y = super(FirstStage, self).transformData(x)
        return self.__transformation(y)

    def __transformation(self, x):
        return x * x

class SecondStage(FirstStage):

    def transformData(self, x):
        y = super(SecondStage, self).transformData(x)
        return self.__transformation(y)

    def __transformation(self, x):
        return x + 1
```

It works as I intended, but there's a potential repetition. If I have N stages, I'll have N identical `transformData` methods where the only thing I change is the name of the current class.

Is there a way to remove this boilerplate? I tried a few things but the results only proved to me that I hadn't understood perfectly how `super` worked.

What I wanted was to define only the method `__transformation` and naturally inherit a `transformData` method that would go up in MRO, call that class' `transformData` method and then call the current class' `__transformation` on the result. Is it possible or do I have to define a new identical `transformData` for each child class?

---

I agree that this is a poor way of implementing a pipeline. That can be done with much simpler (and clearer) schemes. I thought of this as the least modification I could do on a existing model to get a pipeline out of the existing classes without modifying the code too much. I agree this is not the best way to do it. It would be a trick, and tricks should be avoided. Also I thought of it as a way of better understanding how `super` works.

Buuuut. Out of curiosity... is it possible to do it in the above scheme without the `transformData` repetition? This is a genuine doubt. Is there a trick to inherit `transformData` in a way that the `super` call in it is changed to be called on the current class?

It would be a tremendously unclear, unreadable, smart-ass trickery. I know. But is it possible?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you correctly, clarify this: 
  if you have the stages as (C1)s_beg -> (C2)s_common -> (C3)s_common  -> (C4)s_common -> (C5)s_mid -> (C6)s_com_2 -> (C7)s_com_2 ->(C8) s_end
 now if your classes s_common is implemented only once in C2 and so is s_com_2 (only in C6) then you need not have multiple copies of identical funcs. When the call not find a definition of func in C7,  it will automatically go up in hierarchy and try to fetch the senior most transform function (s_common or s_com_2) depending on the call. 

I am not sure if I understand the problem correctly.

Comment: @pranshus it seems like there's a specific point you want me to clarify, but somehow the text was lost.

Comment: sorry i pressed return before finishing my comment.

Comment: Does the example code really work properly? I'd think you'd get the `SecondStage`'s transform applied twice (resulting in x+2) rather than getting the first stage done, then the second (resulting in x^2+1). That's because you're defining a `transformation` method in each, and so `self.transformation(x)` in `FirstStage.transformData` will call `SecondStage.transformation`. If the functions are meant to be unique to the class (avoiding inadvertent overriding), use two leading underscores (i.e. `__transformation`). The Python compiler will "mangle" that into a unique name.

Comment: @Blckknght you're right. I didn't copy my working code and incorrectly reproduced it from memory. Fixed.

Comment: You're still a bit short of working code. You need underscores in your calls to `self.transformation` too. Thinking about it though, I think having an extra function may be more trouble than it's worth. Rather than an extra variable and function, why not just have `transformData` (which you're already overriding) do the computation? It would only need a single line (for simple calculations): `return super().transformData + 1`, or similar (using the Python 3 style of `super` call, for brevity). Or, as the answerers have suggested, stop using inheritance for the pipeline in favor of composition.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think using inheritance for a pipeline is the right way to go.

Instead, consider something like this -- here with "simple" examples and a parametrized one (a class using the `__call__` magic method, but returning a closured function would do too, or even "JITing" one by way of `eval`).

```
def two_power(x):
    return x * x

def add_one(x):
    return x + 1

class CustomTransform(object):
    def __init__(self, multiplier):
        self.multiplier = multiplier

    def __call__(self, value):
        return value * self.multiplier

def transform(data, pipeline):
    for datum in data:
        for transform in pipeline:
            datum = transform(datum)
        yield datum

pipe = (two_power, two_power, add_one, CustomTransform(1.25))
print list(transform([1, 2, 4, 8], pipe))
```

would output

```
[2.5, 21.25, 321.25, 5121.25]
```

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. It's too complicated for a very simple behavior. But I already have the classes and, for another reason, now I need to implement this pipeline behavior. I thought I could do it like this to avoid having to rewrite a lot of code. Maybe it's better to just rewrite it. :)

Maybe I have a lame example too...

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that using inheritance here is rather weird in terms of OOP. And do you really need to define the whole chain of transformations when defining classes?

But it's better to forget OOP here, the task is not for OOP. Just define functions for transformations:

```
def get_pipeline(*functions):
    def pipeline(x):
        for f in functions:
            x = f(x)
        return x
    return pipeline

p = get_pipeline(lambda x: x * 2, lambda x: x + 1)

print p(5)
```

An even shorter version is here:

```
def get_pipeline(*fs):
    return lambda v: reduce(lambda x, f: f(x), fs, v)

p = get_pipeline(lambda x: x * 2, lambda x: x + 1)
print p(5)
```

And here is an OOP solution. It is rather clumsy if compared to the previous one:

```
class Transform(object):
    def __init__(self, prev=None):
        self.prev_transform = prev

    def transformation(self, x):
        raise Exception("Not implemented")

    def transformData(self, x):
        if self.prev_transform:
            x = self.prev_transform.transformData(x)
        return self.transformation(x)

class TransformAdd1(Transform):
    def transformation(self, x):
        return x + 1

class TransformMul2(Transform):
    def transformation(self, x):
        return x * 2

t = TransformAdd1(TransformMul2())
print t.transformData(1) # 1 * 2 + 1
```